# Massive flaw in raft algorithm

Tags: distributed, distributed-system, consensus, raft

So the raft dissertation and paper say this is how to handle append entries:

> Receiver implementation:
>
> 1. Reply false if term < currentTerm (§5.1)
> 2. Reply false if log doesn’t contain an entry at prevLogIndex whose term matches prevLogTerm (§5.3)
> 3. If an existing entry conflicts with a new one (same index but different terms), delete the existing entry and all that follow it
>    (§5.3)
> 4. Append any new entries not already in the log
> 5. If leaderCommit > commitIndex, set commitIndex = min(leaderCommit, index of last new entry)
>
> Leaders:
>
> • Upon election: send initial empty AppendEntries RPCs (heartbeat) to
> each server; repeat during idle periods to prevent election timeouts
> (§5.2)
>
> • If command received from client: append entry to local log, respond
> after entry applied to state machine (§5.3)
>
> • If last log index ≥ nextIndex for a follower: send AppendEntries
> RPC with log entries starting at nextIndex
>
> • If successful: update nextIndex and matchIndex for follower (§5.3)
>
> • If AppendEntries fails because of log inconsistency: decrement
> nextIndex and retry (§5.3)
>
> • If there exists an N such that N > commitIndex, a majority of
> matchIndex[i] ≥ N, and log[N].term == currentTerm: set commitIndex = N
> (§5.3, §5.4).
>
> **Rules for Servers**
> Figure 2: A condensed summary of the Raft consensus algorithm (excluding membership changes and log co

However, this simply will never work in a situation where you are sending more than 1 entry at a time. If I send 3 entries, a single success will only increment by 1, lol. How do I make sense of this? How are we able to confirm that ALL of the entries were sent from nextIndex[serverId] -> to the end of the log?

Comment: What do you mean by "If I send 3 entries, a single success will only increment by 1" - what will be incremented by 1?

Answer (score 0):

I'm assuming your question is around sending multiple AppendEntries when a peer is down or not able to respond, since a leader might accumulate multiple log entries from clients while a peer is down and each AppendEntries RPC will carry potentially different log entries (and values for prevLogIndex and prevLogTerm)

If yes, then this isn't really a flaw but an implementation detail on how you would like to handle multiple AppendEntries going out to the same peer in the cluster and potentially not receiving a response to each AppendEntry but perhaps just one.

Take a look at https://groups.google.com/g/raft-dev/c/PnvThDlMczU